# Resolve Java method with omitted varargs parameter

Tags: java

I have the following classes definition:

```
class A {
String foo(Object par) {
     return par.toString();
  }
}
class B extends A {
 static String foo(String par, Object ... pars) {
   return par.toString();
 }
}
```

If I do a call like  `B.foo("hello");` , then I get a compilation error

error: non-static method foo(Object) cannot be referenced from a static context

Of course `B.foo("hello", (Object[])null);` works just right. However if I rename the virtual method foo, to foo1 for example, then the compilation error gets gone. It means that first variant of a static method call is still valid, however a compiler tries first to match virtual signature. Can someone provide a right explanation the behavior from the Java language specification document?

Answer (score 4):

The method resolution algorithm is defined in the [JLS #15.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). In substance, methods without varargs have priority over methods that have varargs (emphasis mine):

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution ***without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation***. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

As explained in the JLS, it is done that way "*to ensure compatibility with versions of the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0*".

Comment: Indeed if I change static method signature by removing varargs part, static method resolution happened without a problem. However I still would like to see an example why it could be a problem for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

`A.foo` is NOT static while `B.foo` is.

Calling `B.foo("Hello")` is an error because inherited `A.foo` method is NOT static. The calls that you say are working probably shows you a warning?